# updating a data.table column based on matching to another data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have two `data.table` objects in R:
library(data.table)

```
spp <- c('A','B','C','D','E')
state <- c('Z','Q',NA,'Z','Q')
d1 <- data.table(spp,state)

spp <- c('C','B','K')
state <-c('Z','Q','Q')
d2 <- data.table(spp,state)
```

The observation `C` in column `spp` of `d1` has an NA value in column `state`. However, in `d2` the observation `C` in column `spp` has the value `Z` in column `state`. How can I update the `state` column of `d1`, adding the `state` observations from `d2` when there is a `spp` observation that is common to both `d1` and `d2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do a join `on` the 'spp' and assign the 'state' with the second dataset 'state' column i.e. `i.state`

```
d1[d2, state := i.state, on = .(spp)]
```